# Improving the Condition while keeping the column space

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

For a vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ the Krylov subspace is the subspace $\mathcal{K}_k(A,b) = \operatorname{span}\{b,Ab,\dots ,A^kb\}$.

I am currently working with the Matrix $Y = [b | Ab |\dots |A^kb]$ in a numeric application, but for sufficiently large $k$ it's condition converges to zero, since the $A^kb$ converge to an eigenvector and thus the columns become nearly linearly dependent. I am looking for a way to improve the condition while keeping the same column space. This can obviously be improved by orthogonalization, but that is too expensive in my case, as it requires $k^2$ summations and inner products. Is there another way to improve the condition of $Y$?

To be precise, I am working with the vectorization of tensors given in a specific format, so the vectors above can have *very* many entries; basic operations like addition and scalar products are easily executable; procedures like householder transformations are therefore not feasible.

Comment: You mean to say that the matrix $Y_k$ becomes ill conditioned as $k$ increases. Unless you supply the relevant tensor there is very little which can be done. You are more much likely to get a useful reply if you earn 15 points so that you can upvote an answer. It is a small investment on your part, but worth it.

Comment: Column space of $Y$ can be found using the Arnoldi method.